# Python - Detect a starting process

Tags: python, process

I want to detect a starting process on Windows using Python.

For example: Whenever a user starts notepad.exe I want to run some functions in Python..
The script should wait for those process starts.

Can I gather starting processes using Python?

Maybe with 'os' or 'psutil' module?

Hope you understand what I mean.. you are free to ask me for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of hack it by polling the Windows system command, `tasklist`:

```
import time
import subprocess

while True:
    p = subprocess.run(['tasklist'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    if b'notepad.exe' in p.stdout:
        print('Found!')
        break
    print('not yet...')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not aware of any way of interrupting the startup of a process in order to run something *before* the other process actually starts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to accomplish the same functionality but asynchronously?
(i.e. I mean instead of the polling approach you suggested above via time.sleep(..)?